# Explain static and dynamic binding without Overloading and Overriding?

Tags: programming-languages, object-oriented

few days ago I attended a interview, and the interviewer asked me a very common but strange question. **Explain static and dynamic binding without using method overloading and method overriding ?** I explained him the concept but, I am not able to give him the example **without overloading and overriding**. So I want to ask, Is this possible to implement both concept without overloading and overriding ? If yes then can anyone give me the proper link or answer ?

Comment: What a horrible interview question. S/He could just have asked "explain this as I want that to be explained". Maybe the intended answer was to mention the details of a vtable implementation? We'll never know for sure. If you never override methods it hardly matters (except from a performance point of view).